# iOS transparent window / alert / box overlay that shows loading message

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwindow

is there a specific class for displaying a transparent loading box / alert / window, or are people constructing these loading message boxes from UIWindow class?

Here is a picture of what I am talking about.  I am specifically referring to the transparent box / window in the picture that states, "Reloading Data"  I have seen other apps use this type of transparent overlay, and was wondering there was a class for this specific type of window / alert.  When one presses the volume button a similar overlay box appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can see this : [MBProgressHud](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Comment: Link only answers are bad answers. If the link ever dies the answer becomes worthless. Please summarise the page you are linking to here and use the link as backup/reference.